# Postgres - Counting children in level (below) using ltree

Tags: sql, postgresql, ltree

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE foo (text name, path ltree);
```

A couple of inserts

```
INSERT INTO foo (name, path) VALUES ( 'Alice', 'ROOT.first.parent');
INSERT INTO foo (name, path) VALUES ( 'Bob', 'ROOT.second.parent');
INSERT INTO foo (name, path) VALUES ( 'Mistress', 'ROOT.third.parent');
INSERT INTO foo (name, path) VALUES ( 'Ted', 'ROOT.first.parent.child');
INSERT INTO foo (name, path) VALUES ( 'Carol', 'ROOT.second.parent.child');
```

Now I simply want to count the nodes under ROOT. I think I should do:

```
SELECT count(path) FROM foo
WHERE path ~ 'ROOT.*{1}'
```

I would expect 3 but I get 0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fount it! As with all things, RTFM is not a bad advice. The bundled *Subpath* function does the trick. Count distinct occurrences from offset 1, length 1:

```
select count(distinct subpath(path, 1, 1))
from foo
```

3.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need either

```
WHERE path ~ 'ROOT.*{2}'
```

or

```
WHERE path ~ 'ROOT.*.parent'
```

That's because 'first.parent' is two labels, not one. The second WHERE clause looks for paths that end with 'parent', which I think makes your intent clearer.

You can see the sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f2042/1).

Comment: Let me rephrase: ROOT has n children (3 in this case). I don't know their labels. How do I count them? `WHERE path ~ 'ROOT.*{2}'` is a false positive because Alice, Bob, and Mistress have exactly 3 levels. A correct answer to the wrong question.

Comment: An lquery won't answer that question, but the subpath() function will. You already know that. ;)